# SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls12; does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, tls1.2

I am updating Security protocols to my existing 3.5 .net framework application  to work my payment gateways smooth.  I have added following code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls12;
```

in my `Global.asax` in `Application_Start` but it is giving me compile time error that

> The name 'SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions' does not exist in the
>   current context

I was following this link S[upport for TLS System Default Versions included in the .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 SP1 and Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154517/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-.net-framework-2.0-sp2-on-windows-vista-sp2-and-server-2008-sp2) provided by Microsoft.

**Update 1:**

Also tried as told in above link, added both files in project, now I am getting an exception "`System.NotSupportedException`: The requested security protocol is not supported"

**Updated 2:**

Tried as suggested by Jon Davies, but still no luck. same Exception `System.NotSupportedException`

Answer (score 8):

The fix is stated in the article you linked to:

> To include the support for TLS v1.2, include the source files in your project...

In other words - you need to add the `SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions` and `SslProtocolExtensions` types from the article to your own project.

It's a bit of an ugly hack, but is required because TLS 1.2 was released *after* .NET 3.5.

Alternatively if you want to avoid using these extensions and don't mind unlabelled magic numbers in your code, you could ignore the code in the article and just set this instead:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)0x00000C00;
```

Comment: From where should I get these source files,

Comment: Copy the definitions from the **Developer Guidance** section of the article.

Comment: and where should I save that code, because, it looks that It is insidee System.Net namespace which is .net core class

Comment: Just include them in your own project - you might have to turn off some namespace checking rules but otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: let me try, because I am still confuse regarding its usage

Comment: Alternatively it should still work if your change the namespaces to match that of your own project. You can also set the value directly without using the code in the article - I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have already used `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072` and also used that code line you have suggested. same error still exist. I have also added above files in my project but same error

Comment: You've still seeing the `SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions` error? You need to *replace* the line of code from your question with any *one* of the other solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134469/discussion-between-jon-davies-and-qadeer).

Comment: This is incorrect. If you don't correctly install TLS1.1 and 1.2 for .NET 4.0 YOU DO NOT GET THE OPTION TO USE TLS.1.1 THEREFORE THIS LINE IS INVALID System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)0x00000C00; would vote down 100 times if I could

Comment: Thank you so much @Jon Davies
You saved me days worth of work, instead of targeting a .Net 4.5, i used your hack and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Also check  using System.Security.Authentication   is at the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a project with VB.net instead.
So for someone who need this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(&HC00, SecurityProtocolType)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).